# Конфигурация Node.js + MongoDB + Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, mongodb

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с трудностью по подключению Базы данных к проекту. Есть готовая база данных (папка с файлами). Нужно эту БД прикрутить к проекту на Node.js. У меня стоит релиз Ubuntu 16.04. Я установил саму MongoDB и сделал два файла в etc/systemd/system. один файл mongodb.conf - для конфигурации базы данных, и второй файл nodeserver.service - для проекта.
Содержание первого файла:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targe
```

Содержание второго файла:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyProject
Documentation=https://www.myproject.ru
After=network.target
Requires=mongodb.service

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=8000
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
# Output to syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodeserver
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /path/to/myproject/server.js
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/myproject
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

И есть файл в корне директории проекта config.sample:

```
  name                     : MYPROJECT
  version                  : 0.6.0
  author                   : User
  database                 : mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydatabase
  dateformatShort          : DD/MM/YYYY
  dateformatLong           : DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
  manager-url              : /index
  phone                    : anynumb
  default-language         : ru

/// какой-то текст....
```

Как мне прикрутить Базу данных которая локально находится на диске в папке к этому проекту?

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить ключ `--dbpath /path/to/db` к `mongod` в `ExecStart` сервиса базы.

---

Также можно добавить конфигурацию в файл конфигурации (простите за тавтологию):

`/etc/mongod.conf:` - файл конфигурации указан у вас в сервисе mongod

```
dbpath = /path/to/db
```

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, в файл конфигурации дописал строку dbpath = /home/sergey/myproject/dump (в dump) находится база данных (файлы). Запускаю базу данных, она работает нормально через mongo выбираю базу данных use dump, запуская файл server.js и в терминале пишется:
Dict is not loaded
You need to install or update database form dump directory

Comment: Может быть у вас там таки не база, а дампы бэкапа? Тогда нужно копать в сторону mongorestore